# Multiple value slot in Cloudformation for Amazon Lex V2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

I'm building a bot that needs to catch multiple users mentions (I'm building this using a CloudFormation template). For that I use a slot, but this slot needs to store one or more usernames.
According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/multi-valued-slots.html), there are three requisites to do that:

- Slot type must be custom type.
- Slot must be declared under `en_US` locale.
- Slot must be defined to `AllowMultipleValues`.

So, I tried this:

```
# [...]
Resources:
  MyBot:
    Type: AWS::Lex::Bot
    Properties:
      # [...]
      BotLocales:
        - LocaleId: "en_US"
          # [...]
          SlotTypes:
            # [...]
            - Name: !Sub "user_${env}"
              Description: "..."
              ValueSelectionSetting:
                ResolutionStrategy: ORIGINAL_VALUE
                RegexFilter:
                  Pattern: "@?\\w{1,100}"
          Intents:
            # [...]
            - Name: !Sub "AnIntent_${env}"
              Description: "Intent that does what I need"
              SampleUtterances:
                # [...]
              # [...]
              SlotPriorities:
                - Priority: 1
                  SlotName: user
              FulfillmentCodeHook:
                Enabled: true
                IsActive: true    
              Slots:
                - Name: "user"
                  Description: "..."
                  SlotTypeName: !Sub "user_${env}"
                  MultipleValuesSetting:
                    AllowMultipleValues: true
                  ValueElicitationSetting:
                    SlotConstraint: "Required"
                    PromptSpecification:
                      MessageGroupsList:
                        - Message:
                            PlainTextMessage:
                              Value: "..."
                      MaxRetries: 3
                      AllowInterrupt: false
```

As you can see, I'm declaring a custom slot type and then referencing it into my only Intent through its name in `SlotTypeName` property of my `Slots` section. So, at first sigh, requisites are ok: custom slot type, declared for `en_US` locale and multi value allowed.

When I try to deploy these changes, I get the following message:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Importing MyBot failed due to [Couldn't import the bot. SlotTypeConfiguration and CustomSlotTypeDefinition both cannot be specified together. Validation error occurred at Slot Type user_dev for Locale en_US. Check the value and try your request again.]. The import could not be completed." (RequestToken: [...], HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

I also tried by configuring `ParentSlotTypeSignature: "AMAZON.AlphaNumeric"` in the `SlotType` definition. In this case the error message tells me that `AllowMultipleValues` is not allowed for `AMAZON.AlphaNumeric` SlotType.

Seems the error is at `SlotType` definition but I'm not able to find it. So, could anyone help to identify what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!